# SharedPreference values form xml

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I'm writing preferences page (preferences.xml), and trying to retrieve values from resources file. This code is working;

```
<PreferenceScreen ...

 <ListPreference
     android:entries="@array/tips"
     android:entryValues="@array/tips"
     android:title="Tip rate"
     />
```

But this is not;

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="@integer/invoiceNumberNext" // this doesn't work
    android:key="invoice_number_next"
    android:title="Next Invoice #"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    />
```

I have this in my defaults.xml page which is under res/values

```
<resources>
    <integer name="invoiceNumberNext">1001</integer>
</resources>
```

Any idea why I'm not able to fetch some values?

Comment: have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: in which folder is integer.xml? It must be res/values/integer.xml....

Comment: I tried to clean. Resouce is under defauls.xml not integer.xml @Opiatefuchs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you misplaced your value. If you reference a value with `@integer` it must be in a xml file called (what a mystery...) `integer.xml`. This file must be in the folder structure

`res/values/integer.xml`

So right click on `values` folder and click **"New-->Values resource file"** and then enter `integer.xml` Here, now add your resources like you have done....tataaaa....you can use it.

### EDIT

As I hadn´t understand the original question correctly, I have to elaborate this answer. Of course it is possible to create a file `defaults.xml` and put an `<integer>` item inside, and this is still available by `@integer`. So, at the beginning of this question, it seems that you misplaced the file into the wrong directory. But that isn´t the case so your problem must be anywhere else. If the `default.xml` is in `res/values`, it should work.

Comment: You are right! I tough It's related auto generate R file, and It's collecting all strings under strings etc. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help... :)

Comment: And by the way, the R file generates automatically resource identifiers. You can´t edit it, as soon as you do it, by the next build, it´s regenrated and your entries are deleted. It´s like Hammer said....can´t touch this....

Comment: Thanks. So I cannot create file called defaults.xml and call variables from that file am I right? It must be integers.xml, bools.xml or strings.xml etc.

Comment: Okay, so now I realized that I misunderstood your question. I thought your problem was a misplaced file, but it isn´t the case so my answer is not absolute correct. For sure you can define a file defaults.xml inside res/values folder and can reference @integer from there. So your problem must be caused by another issue...can we check again how was your old problem caused?